# Push notifications to android app without having access to database

Tags: android, notifications, push

I want to display a notification to my android app from [this](https://gekon.technologypark.cz/en/) website. I want to display the blue square that says `Season 2018 is closed` as a notification on my android app. This quote is added by the admin of the page so I want when he adds more, to display them as notifications. Is there a way without having access to the database?

**UPDATE**

Or if it's any way to display the notification when the admin updates the database.I've seen firebase notifications are good but i want the admin not to go to a firebase page,instead he will continue uploading from his webpage(there are more than one admin also).

Comment: If you want to do it without a cloud messaging solution, you can set up a regular, time based Job (e.g. with WorkManager), grab the website, parse it and show a notification, if your conditions for show a notification are met.

Comment: @Christopher  I don't have a problem doing it with cloud messaging but is it possible the admin to update his webpage and i can retrieve the push notifications to my app?Or does the admin needs to go to an other page(probably firebase page for sending notifications) to set the notification?

Comment: Please describe the setup of the website. If it's a regular CMS, maybe a plugin for push notifications is already available.

Comment: @Christopher i'm sorry i don't have access to the website.I only make the android app.That's why i'm saying if it's possible to do it without firebase.But if there is a way that admin can post from his website and firebase somehow send notifications there is no problem!(if there is i can contact the admin)

Answer (score 2):

In Android, for push notification, you can use Firebase notification. It's easy way to add notification functionality in Android app.

https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Open this link and follow these steps to implement push notification.

Comment: I know that i can do it with firebase but i just want to do it without using it.Only get the data tha admins upload in their website(gekon.cz) and display thems as notifications